# Using JQuery Lightbox within AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, lightbox

Hey. So this is probably a very noob problem but I'm not good enough to fix it. Basically... I have a gallery that I am loading into the page via AJAX. It looks simply like this:

```
    <div id="gallery">
            <a href="Image1.jpg"><img src="Image1Thumb.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="Image2.jpg" title=""><img src="Image2Thumb.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
```

But because it's being loaded in as AJAX content, JQuery/Lightbox is not working and I've no idea how can I get the script to run/recognise this newly loaded content.

Thanks!

[Note: The [JQuery Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) I am using.]

Comment: The URL is dead. ([Long live the URL?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_king_is_dead,_long_live_the_king!))

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the code for the light box after the ajax content has loaded.

e.g.

```
$.get('gallery.html',function(data){
    $('body').append(data);
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
},'html');
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I'm being dumb but isn't this loading my gallery as soon as the page loads (as well as activating the lightbox)? I have the gallery loading via an existing link, like this: <a href="#Gallery" onClick="sendRequest('Gallery.html');">Gallery</a> and want the lightbox to activate when it's loaded.

Comment: In your `sendRequest` function you need to add the script to create the lightbox gallery, which needs to be run after you have loaded the content of `Gallery.html` into the page.